# Is there a philosophical theory that provides rules for the classification of the hardness of scientific/philosophical theories?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

A theory that could be used to classify(or at least rate) other theories in terms of their groundedness to reality and their ability to predict stuff.

Comment: Scientific theory choice is a large topic in philosophy of science, but philosophy, even philosophy of science, is not structured as a collection of "theories of", see [Theory Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_choice), [Underdetermination of Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/) and [Epistemic Values](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-objectivity/#EpiConVal).

Comment: "hardness" ????

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think they are alluding to the hard/soft science informal classification.

Comment: @Schiphol - Thanks :-) I cannot imagine any significant measure of the "degree of hardness" of sciences... Of course we have science using mathematics to formulate their theories, sciences using mathematical formulas to make computations and purely "descriptive" sciences. But to measure this in some significant way...

Comment: But this kind of rough, informal, underspecified questions are precisely the philosopher's bread and butter :)

Comment: @Conifold your answers are always folding me the right way.